# Adsense ads only for one topic?

Tags: google, google-adsense

In my AdSense account under sites I can block some categories, but this is limited and I cannot do it exactly, so my question is it is possible to limit ads only for games?

Comment: Limiting the ads that can run will severely limit the potential income from ads.   Many AdSense ads are targeted at the user rather than based on content.  For example re-targeting ads show for sites the user previously visited.  Limiting ads to games would stop the case of ads that ask the user to come back and complete the purchase of items that were in the shopping cart of some other site.